# iOS comparing NSDictionary values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, compare, nsarray

I'm fetching two `JSON`s and store them individually as `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

This is what the `JSON` data structures looks like

```
(
        {
            Cells = (
                {
                    ValueName = "name";
                    Text = "John Appleseed";
                },
                {
                    "Option": {
                        "Text": "19"
                    },
                    ValueName = "age"
                }, etc...
            )
        },
        {
           Cells = (
                {
                    ValueName = "name";
                    Text = "John Appleseed";
                },
                {
                    ValueName = "age",
                    "Option": {
                        "Text": "19"
                    }
                }, etc...
            )
        }
)
```

---

```
{
    "map": {
        "first": "name",
        "second": "age"
    }, etc...
}
```

---

The two has values that needs to be cross referenced (as one contains all data (`allData`), and the other contains a "map" (`mapData`) of what data is needed).

How may I compare all the values of `allData` with all the values of `mapData` while, if possible, keeping simplicity and memory in mind?

A great approach would be to use `containsObject` matching `[allData allValues]` with `[mapData allValues]` and being given back an `NSArray` with the `object` of the match. Alas, this is not the case. The approach perfectly illustrates what I wish to accomplish.

My initial approach is slow, memory hogging and ugly (wrote this from memory):

```
NSArray *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allDataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&JSONSerializationError];
NSDictionary *mapData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mapDataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&JSONSerializationError];
NSMutableDictionary *resultData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (int count = 0; count<allData.count; count++) {
    id dataValue = [allData objectAtIndex:count];
    for (id key in mapData) {
        if ([[mapData objectForKey:key] containsObject:dataValue]) {
            [resultData setObject:[dataValue objectForKey:@"value"] forKey:key]
        }
    }
}
```

It's also important to be able to reference to each match of the values that match (as done in my approach).

---

This is not an opinion based question as optimisation and memory usage is not an opinion.

Comment: Apart from the original JSON results and `resultData` your approach does not allocate any objects. So, how do you want to reduce this? The only way to bring down memory usage is to deserialize the `allData` JSON in a SAX style and drop non-matching items immediately.

Comment: Example data would be useful to understand the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using this data model is memory efficient and pretty fast (clocked in at an average time of 0.001 sec with `allData`'s length of 1000 lines).

---

By extracting all wanted values from `mapData` and placing them in an `NSArray` the values can easily be matched with the values of `allData`.

When looping thru the `mapDataArray` a secondary loop can be created for going thru `allData`'s values. If `mapDataArray containsObject` returns true, the data can be stored in a momentary storage dictionary.

This allows for easy management of what data is needed and what can be ignored. It is important that the momentary storage is created inside of the first loop (as you'll see in a moment).

If and when all the values from the `mapDataArray` is found (by checking `mapDataArray.count` with `momentaryData.count`) we can `break` the current loop (thus saving time and memory).

It's probably easier to just look at the code to understand what is really going on.

---

The data objects as referenced in the question.

```
NSArray *allData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:allDataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&JSONSerializationError];
NSDictionary *mapData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mapDataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&JSONSerializationError];
```

‏
Creating the `mapDataArray`, looping thru it, creating the momentary dictionary, appending found objects and appending the momentary data to `resultData`.

```
NSArray *mapDataArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

mapDataArray = [[mapDataArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[[mapData objectForKey:@"map"] objectForKey:@"first"]] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[[mapData objectForKey:@"map"] objectForKey:@"second"]];
mapDataArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:mapDataArray] array]; //Remove duplicates

NSMutableDictionary *resultData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (int count = 0; count<allData.count; count++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *momentaryData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    int dataNumber = count;

    NSArray *literal = [[allData objectAtIndex:dataNumber] objectForKey:@"Cells"];
    for (int count = 0; count<literal.count; count++) {
        id literal = [[[allData objectAtIndex:dataNumber] objectForKey:@"Cells"] objectAtIndex:count];

        if ([mapDataArray containsObject:[literal objectForKey:@"ValueName"]]) {
            id value = [literal objectForKey:@"Text"];

            if (!value) {
                value = [literal objectForKey:@"Option"];
                if (value && ![value isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
                    value = [value objectForKey:@"Text"];
                } else {
                    value = @"";
                }
            }

            [momentaryData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value] forKey:[literal objectForKey:@"ValueName"]];

            if (mapDataArray.count == momentaryData.count) {
                break; //We have what we came for...
            }
        }
    }

    [resultData setObject:momentaryData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", dataNumber]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `arrays` or `dictionaries` using `isEqual:`.

For `arrays` it compares whether the `arrays` have the same number of elements or if the matching elements are equal.

For `dictionaries` it checks if both have the same number of keys, if set of keys is equal and if each key in one `dictionary` has the same value as the matching key in the other `dictionary`.